# How to determine if a function is differentiable

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, derivatives, limits-without-lhopital

**Question**

Determine the values of $a$ and $b$ such that the following function is differentiable at 0.

$$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
ax^3cos(\frac 1 x) + bx + b, & \text{if }x \lt 0 \\
\sqrt{a + bx}, & \text{if }x \geq 0
\end{cases}$$

**My solution**

For $f$ to be differentiable at $0$, $f$ must first be continuous at $0$.

$$\implies \lim\limits_{x\to0^-}f(x) = \lim\limits_{x\to0^+}f(x)$$

Consider

\begin{align}
\lim\limits_{x\to0^-}f(x) & =
\lim\limits_{x\to0^-}[ax^3cos(\frac 1 x) + bx + b].
\\[5 mm]
\because \lim\limits_{x\to0^-}ax^3cos(\frac 1 x) & =
\lim\limits_{x\to0^-}bx
\\[5 mm] & =
0
\end{align}

$$\therefore \lim\limits_{x\to0^-}f(x) = b$$

Then, consider

\begin{align}
\lim\limits_{x\to0^+}f(x) & =
\lim\limits_{x\to0^+}\sqrt{a + bx}
\\[5 mm] & =
\sqrt{a}.
\end{align}

$$\implies a = b^2$$

Furthermore, for $f$ to be differentiable at $0$,

$$\lim\limits_{x\to0^-}\frac {f(x) - \sqrt{a}} x = \lim\limits_{x\to0^+}\frac {f(x) - \sqrt{a}} x$$

When $a = b^2$,

\begin{align}
\lim\limits_{x\to0^+}\frac {f(x) - \sqrt{a}} x & =
\lim\limits_{x\to0^+}\frac {\sqrt{a + bx} - \sqrt{a}} x
\\[5 mm] & =
\lim\limits_{x\to0^+}\frac b {\sqrt{a + bx} + \sqrt{a}}
\\[5 mm] & =
\frac b {2\sqrt{a}}
\\[5 mm] & =
\frac 1 2
\\[5 mm]
\implies \lim\limits_{x\to0^-}\frac {f(x) - \sqrt{a}} x & =
\lim\limits_{x\to0^-}\frac {ax^3cos(\frac 1 x) + bx + b - \sqrt{a}} x
\\[5 mm] & =
\lim\limits_{x\to0^-}\frac {b^2x^3cos(\frac 1 x) + bx} x
\\[5 mm] & =
\lim\limits_{x\to0^-}[b^2x^2cos(\frac 1 x) + b]
\\[5 mm] & =
\frac 1 2
\end{align}

$$\because \lim\limits_{x\to0^-}b^2x^2cos(\frac 1 x) = 0$$

$$\therefore b = \frac 1 2$$

$$\implies a = \frac 1 4$$

---

I would like to know if my proposed solution is logical and correct. Moreover, any alternative solutions that are more elegant or succinct are welcomed as well :)

Thank you all in advance!

**Edit**

Following a discussion with MPW, looks like all is well, except perhaps the fact that

$$\implies a = b^2$$

should have been left as

$$\implies \sqrt{a} = b$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks essentially correct and nicely detailed to me, good work.

My only comment would be that you're assuming $b\geq 0$ when you use $\sqrt{b^2} = b$, so it might be worth considering the computations under the assumption $b<0$ to see if you get a second solution (I haven't pursued this). Note this would give that $\sqrt{b^2} = -b$.

On the face of it, I don't see an immediate reason to exclude $b<0$.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer! I might be blind, but may I know where I used the fact that $\sqrt{b^2} = b$?

Comment: It was in the calculation of the second limit, where $bx + b-\sqrt{a}$ becomes $bx$. This is because you used $b-\sqrt{a} = b-\sqrt{b^2} = b-b = 0$. This assumes $\sqrt{b^2}=b$, i.e., b$\geq 0$. It may well be that the limit doesn't exist without this assumption, but it should be considered even if it is then eliminated.

Comment: Ah, but on closer inspection, when I was equating the left and right hand limits to check for the continuity of $f$ (at the beginning), isn't the actual equation that I arrive at supposed to be $\sqrt{a} = b$? I merely squared both sides to get $a = b^2$. It is not the other way around right? So correct me if I'm wrong, but shouldn't I then be able to just substitute $\sqrt{a}$ for $b$, without regard for whether $b$ is negative or positive etc.?

Comment: You're right. So $b<0$ is not a possibility, and you have now polished the proof completely. Your conclusion that $b=\sqrt{a}$ implies not only that $a=b^2$ but also that $b\geq 0$ (which might be noted in the proof). Good job!